# Selecting everything with WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm currently working on a PHP project where multiple access rights exists. The logic is simple:
- When your access level is 2, you can see a list of your own projects only
- When your access level is 3, you can see ALL projects

So in SQL:
First one:

```
SELECT project_name FROM projects
```

Second one:

```
SELECT project_name FROM projects WHERE user_id = user_id
```

The problem is that I'm using PDO with prepared statements and such queries are executed multiple times across the script. This is how it looks like:

```
if ($_SESSION['access_level'] == 3) {
    $sql = "SELECT project_name FROM projects";
  } else {
    $sql = "SELECT project_name FROM projects WHERE user_id = ?";
}

$res = $db->prepare($sql);

// Some more PHP 

if ($_SESSION['access_level'] == 3)
      $res->execute();
    else
      $res->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id']));
```

As I'm doing this in multiple parts of the script, it becomes a mess. Is there a better way to do this? Personally I was thinking of a WHERE-clause where every record is selected. That way this would be possible at the start of the script:

```
if ($_SESSION['access_level'] == 3)
      $id = *;
    else
      $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Now querying is much easier:

```
$res = $db->prepare("SELECT project_name FROM projects WHERE user_id = ?");
$res->execute(array($id));
```

(Now it will get all records when your access level is 3, but only your own when you're only level 2)

This looks like a pretty dump solution imo as I'm not really usng the WHERE clause how it should be used. Also, using * is just not possible.

What's the best option for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the solution in completely wrong way.

Every time you face a situation where you doing somethin in multiple parts of the script, and it become a mess, You have to create **a function**.

In fact, you are still writing all this ugly repeated code with prepare, execute, fetch, prepare, execute, fetch, prepare, execute, fetch - for the every query on the page. Doesn't it looks like a mess for you?

So, you have to create **two** functions.

general purpose one, just to fetch some value out of query without repeating useless code, to use it like this:

```
$proj_names_arr = $db->getColumn("SELECT project_name FROM projects");
```

and one mentioned by Raisen, based on the first one, to be used like this

```
$proj_names_arr = getProjects();
```

It will be the only **real** improvement of your code

As for the function, it's not that hard
a rough example:

```
function getColumn() {
  $args  = func_get_args();
  $query = array_shift($args);
  $res = $db->prepare($query);
  $res->execute($args);
  $data = array();
  while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $data[] = $row[0];
  }
  return $data;
}
```

so, it can be called

```
$proj_names = $db->getColumn("SELECT project_name FROM projects WHERE user_id = ?",
                             $_SESSION['user_id']);
```

Comment: About that function: I didn't explain it correctly - It's not the exact same code, so a function getProjects() doesn't work. About the getColumn(): I was thinking already of writing a simple PDO wrapper, but I'm not using PDO for a long time and I'm afraid it's pretty hard to do that correctly. But I'll give it a try for some common features like inserting, retreiving some records, etc.

Comment: @Bv202 well, explain it correctly then. I see no reason why getProjects() whouldn't work

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier to keep the `where` clauses in a variable, as well as the bind parameters, and then compose the query when running it:

```
<?php

$sql = 'SELECT project_name FROM projects';
$where = array();
$parameters = array();


if ($_SESSION['access_level'] !== 3) {
    $where[] = 'user_id = ?';
    $parameters = array($_SESSION['user_id']);
}



if( !empty($where) ){
    $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(', ', $where);
}
$res = $db->prepare($sql);

$res->execute($parameters);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about an SQL like that:

```
$sql = 'SELECT project_name FROM projects WHERE user_id = ? OR 3 = ?';
$res = $db->prepare($sql);
$res->execute(array($id, $access_level);
```

Comment: This looks like the easiest solution so far, thank you. But I don't think it's a good programming technique.

Comment: A good programming technique would be to create a factory that returns different objects based on your access_level which in turn would use different SQL statements to generate their results. The second best option, if you don't mind putting a little more stain on your db would be to replace the WHERE clause be user_id LIKE ? and using either the user_id or % as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function such as *getProjects()* where it will return the projects according to the user level.

Use Alvaro's code for example inside the function and return the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand: You want a `WHERE`-Statement, thats always true?

```
WHERE 1 = 1
```

Comment: Yes, something like that. But I would still need to be able to pass useful data so that won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

> As I'm doing this in multiple parts of the script, it becomes a mess.

[Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). If you find yourself repeating blocks of code, that's a sign that you should be refactoring that common code into a function or method.

You can also get rid of some of the more minor repetitions by appending extra information to your query rather than rewriting it, and using something like `bindParam()` to add the additional parameter, rather than modifying your `execute()` statement:

```
$userOnly = ($_SESSION['access_level'] == 2);

$sql = "SELECT project_name FROM projects";

if ($userOnly) {
    $sql .= " WHERE user_id = ?";
}

$res = $db->prepare($sql);

if ($userOnly) {
 $res=>bindParam(bindParam(1, $$_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
}

$res->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id']));
```

Personally, I think that's a bit neater than the original, since the parts that only apply to the lower access level are clearly marked and self-contained, not repeating code already presented.

Also, using a new variable with a descriptive name for the access level stops you from repeating magic numbers, and gives you a single point of change.

Hope that helps.